# Bare verb vs gerund: watching them play or playing

Tags: infinitive-vs-gerund, verbs-of-perception

> 1. I love watching them **play** in the park.
> 2. I love watching them **playing** in the park.

Which one is correct or natural if both are correct? 
Why would you use the bare verb over the gerund in sentences like this?

Answer (score 1):

The first option is correct.

The reason for that is the second sentence is actually two gerunds nested inside of each other. Let me show you what I mean.

> I love **watching them play in the park**.

The bolded text is the direct object of the sentence. "Watching them play" is a gerund phrase. "In the park" is just a prepositional phrase, and like most, it can be removed from the sentence without taking away anything from the grammatical structure or correctness. "I love watching them play." is also a valid sentence and a complete thought.

> I love **watching them** ***playing in the park***.

"Playing in the park" (or I suppose more technically just "playing") is a gerund phrase on its own, apart from "watching them". So what you are effectively saying is "I love watching them [noun]." As you probably know, nouns cannot be used as verbs.

> I love watching playing children.

This is a correct sentence because "playing" is a participle used to describe "children," but it is a little awkward to say so you will not likely hear or see it in normal conversation. A more common version would be "I love watching children at play." I just wanted to play devil's advocate and show you what it would take to make a valid sentence with both "watching" and "playing" in the sentence, while preserving the meaning.

Comment: Thank you. How about these comparison: 10. I see a child playing. 20. I see a playing child. 11. I am seeing a child playing. 21. I am seeing a child play.

Comment: They're all technically correct. The first two have a <subject> <verb> structure, but the last two have a <subject> <is> <participle> structure ("I am seeing"). In English, the second structure is usually redundant unless you are asking a question ("Is the child playing?"). This redundancy makes the last two a little awkward. The first two are virtually the same sentence.

Comment: There's some ambiguity; you could make the argument that "playing in the park" is actually a participial phrase modifying the subject "I".